# Found Zombie Object, but Cannot Find Responsible Caller

Tags: xcode, nszombie

I am so confused by this problem. I used Instruments to find a Zombie in my code. Usually I would just go through the list of responsible callers and fix it. The only problem is one of the responsible caller methods doesn't exist in my code. I can't find it!

[image]

I can't find -[SpriteSheet setImage:]. The setImage: method is nowhere in my code. It sounds crazy to me, but when I do a textual style search of my code, it comes up empty. I looked through the SpriteSheet class, and there are no methods called setImage:.

Please tell me I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the setImage method is likely synthezide from a property on the SpriteSheet class:
`@property(retain) UIImage *image;` => `@synthesize image;` => there is code because it is autogenerated.

but it seems you release the image in Enemy::dealloc but try to access it again in there. (last 3 lines)